# VS Code - Configure Run Python File In Terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I have a python environment called nem that I created using Conda, however in VS Code when I right click and select 'Run Python File in Terminal' I get the below error. BUT I know this package is not an issue as I can open up a new windows terminal outside of VS Code and run the commands below and everything works great.

```
activate nem
python index.py
```

I have also had issues where the output in the terminal is being suppressed even though the application is running. I'm not sure what the root cause of this is, and whether its directly related to Conda. However does anyone know of a solution to this? Or how to configure VS Code's 'Run Python File in Terminal' to just use the commands above.

> Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> PS C:\Users\nikhil\Git Repos\natatorium-energy-model> conda
>   activate nem PS C:\Users\nikhil\Git
>   Repos\natatorium-energy-model> &
>   C:/Users/nikhil/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/nem/python.exe
>   "c:/Users/nikhil/Git Repos/natatorium-energy-model/index.py"
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:/Users/nikhil/Git
>   Repos/natatorium-energy-model/index.py", line 8, in 
>       from apps import analyse   File "c:\Users\nikhil\Git Repos\natatorium-energy-model\apps\analyse.py", line 17, in 
>       import pyarrow.parquet as pq   File "C:\Users\nikhil\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\nem\lib\site-packages\pyarrow__init__.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from pyarrow.lib import cpu_count, set_cpu_count ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. PS
>   C:\Users\nikhil\Git Repos\natatorium-energy-model>

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom left corner, change the python interpreter to the one in your environment.